# What do you mean? Whatever do you mean?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

What do you mean? 
Whatever do you mean? 
Which one is correct?
I have a confusion about these two sentences. 
I just hope I will be satisfied.

Comment: *What, which, how, who-ever, etc* are used on affirmative sentences I think.

Comment: Whatever do you mean? In my opinion , this is an emphatic sentence. Let's wait for other teachers.

Comment: If it was that, It'd be *whatever you mean?* I think.

Comment: I have looked for this sentence on Google, I think there is a solution to the problem. I checked it but couldn't comprehend. That's why I shared this here.

Comment: I think they are both right, the only difference I can think of is "*whatever* do you mean", has a hint of disbelieve or just exclamation in general.

Comment: I think the "whatever" version also sounds a bit dated, maybe literary. I dont't think I've ever heard it in conversation.

Answer (score 2):

> **What** do you mean?

This is just a literal question.

When you say:

> **Whatever** do you mean?

there is a hint of disbelief. For example:

> I heard Johnny is a lazy boy.
>   **Whatever** do you mean?

*whatever* by itself can also indicate disagreement. For example:

> I don't like your new hairstyle. It is too short.
>   **Whatever.**

Comment: In the last example, "whatever" is basically short for "whatever you think is fine with me" which is another way of saying that you don't really care what the other person thinks.  It's a fairly common thing for teenagers to say when they don't agree with their parents, and is often considered a bit childish.

Comment: "Whatever do you mean?" can also show sarcasm.

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whatever-do-you-mean.3739171/#post-19087729